# Git log scrolls to the bottom by default

Tags: git

I have this weird issue that `git log` scrolls down to the first commit. Has anyone seen this as well? Really weird

Comment: I guess there might be something going on with you terminal. Or an alias setting `log` to `git log --reverse`

Comment: I already looked in my ``.zshrc``. It also happens in bash and other terminal emulators. I is also different from ``git --reverse``, because it shows it in the normal order but then quickly scrolls down.

Comment: How about `git -c core.pager=less log` or `git -c core.pager=more log`?

Comment: Ah yes, I had my pager set to ``most`` and it wasn't present yet on my new installation. So missing pager...